# How to call standard javascript functions in AngularJS templates?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I have JavaScript functions inside of AngularJS curly braces/notation?

I have tried the code below. If you un-comment my JS functions they don't work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  
<p>Some formula: {{ 1+2 }}</p>

<!--

<p>Some function: {{Math.sin(12)}}</p>

<p>Some constructor: {{new Date()}}</p>

-->
  
</div>
```

Is it possible to unlock/enable?

**UPDATE**

Okay, in simple `{{}}` functions can be wrapped into UDFs. But what about functions inside cell template in [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/)? I still can use simple formulas there, but can't use any functions, even UDFs defined in `$scope`.

In the sample below, `cellTemplateWorks` uses simple addition and it works. The template `cellTemplateNotWorks` uses call to `myFunction` and not works in template (while works in simple placeholder).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid', 'myControllers']);

var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.myData = [{"x": 1}, {"x": 2}, {"x": 3}, {"x": 4}, {"x": 5}];
    
    var cellTemplateWorks = "<div \
       class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text>\
        {{row.entity[col.field]+1}}\
        </span></div>";

    
     var cellTemplateNotWorks = "<div \
        class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text>\
        {{myFunction(row.entity[col.field])}}\
        </span></div>";
    
    $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'myData',
            columnDefs: [
//                {field: 'x', displayName: 'x', },
//              {field: 'x', displayName: 'sin(x)', cellTemplate: cellTemplateNotWorks},
              {field: 'x', displayName: 'sin(x)', cellTemplate: cellTemplateWorks},
            ]
        };
    
    $scope.myFunction = function(arg) {
        return Math.sin(arg);
    };
  }]);
```

```css
.myGrid {
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="styleSheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.css"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <p>MyFunction does work: {{myFunction(12)}}</p>
      
      <p>MyFunction does not work in UI Grid:
      
        <div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="myGrid"></div>
      
      
      </p>
        
      
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You cannot have functions inside of the curly brackets in AngularJS from my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> Angular Expressions vs. JavaScript Expressions Angular expressions are
>   like JavaScript expressions with the following differences:
>
> **Context**: JavaScript expressions are evaluated against the global
>   window. In Angular, expressions are evaluated against a scope object.
>
> **Forgiving**: In JavaScript, trying to evaluate undefined properties
>   generates ReferenceError or TypeError. In Angular, expression
>   evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null.
>
> **No Control Flow Statements**: You cannot use the following in an Angular
>   expression: conditionals, loops, or exceptions.
>
> **No Function Declarations**: You cannot declare functions in an Angular
>   expression, even inside ng-init directive.
>
> **No RegExp Creation With Literal Notation**: You cannot create regular
>   expressions in an Angular expression.
>
> **No Object Creation With New Operator**: You cannot use new operator in
>   an Angular expression.
>
> **No Comma And Void Operators**: You cannot use , or void operators in an
>   Angular expression.
>
> **Filters**: You can use filters within expressions to format data before
>   displaying it.
>
> If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a
>   controller method and call the method from your view. If you want to
>   eval() an Angular expression yourself, use the $eval() method.

The last paragraph explains the suggested way to implement this.

---

UPDATE:

Looks like you are using UI grid. The reason why the expression doesn't work is because this grid has a different scope than the one in which you declared your function. If you want to access the scope of the controller you should use [`grid.appScope`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope):

```
 var cellTemplateNotWorks = "<div \
    class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text>\
    {{grid.appScope.myFunction(row.entity[col.field])}}\
    </span></div>";
```

In this example you can access `myFunction` inside the template using `grid.appScope`.

Comment: I don't see any prohibition of using of function calls. So why don't they work?

Comment: They don't work because this is not supported. If you want to evaluate some complex expressions that involve function calls, simply wrap this logic in a function on the `$scope` variable and call this function.

Comment: So, you mean calling of standard functions is not supported, while calling of user defined functions is supported?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can call functions defined on the `$scope` object. For example in your controller you could define a function: `$scope.myFunction = function(x) { return Math.sin(x); }` and then use this function inside an expression: `{{ myFunction(12) }}`.

Comment: See my update please. I have defined function and it worked. But it worked only in simple `{{}}`. If I use nested constructions like in `UI Grid` it still not work. May be it is possible to import parent context or something?

Comment: OK, but that's an entirely different question. Usually it is not good idea to update your question so much but rather ask a new one. See my updated answer for how to make this work. Use `grid.appScope.myFunction`

Comment: This is the question. I tried to use function in cell template and failed with some error message (unexpected token). I started to prepare `SSCCE` and found that using `ui-grid` is not required and functions are not callable even in simple templates. How would I know it is different effect? The problem is same, error message is same. Even now I don't understand how it is "entirely different".

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still don't understand, why does it work?  Why some functions are not callable at all, another functions are just callable directly and third functions are callable with some random prefix? Can I have some universal understanding on how to find these prefixes? May be there is also some prefix to call `Math.sin()` without wrapping, how can we know?

Comment: P.P.S. Also I don't understand your documentation excerpt. It contains no word about function calls and look irrelevant for me, I am really SORRY.

Comment: It works because of the specifics of the third party component you are using. I strongly suggest you reading the documentation of any third party component that you are willing to integrate into your application. In the case of UI Grid it is explicitly mentioned that you could use `grid.appScope` in order to access the main controller scope. It is specific to this component. So I don't know what do you expect me to say: maybe you should ask the authors of this component why they decided to implement it that way. I cannot provide you with an answer to that question.

Comment: Also I cannot respond to your question as to why you cannot use arbitrary functions in Angular expressions. It's how the authors of this framework decided to implement this functionality. So it is a question that should be brought to their attention.